# Dependency injection need some explanation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

I have been working alot on MVC3 now a days and use Dependency Injection ninject etc.

I find it useful in Testing, don't make concrete implementation of classes like Model but instead injected.

My Questions:

How do we explain DI. Any simple definition to it.?

The benefits of DI?

Can we use DI in ASP.NET web forms?

Thanks

Comment: [The wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) has a decent definition for DI. Do checkout the external links. For webforms, see [this post](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ioc_and_di_with_web_forms).

Comment: Take a look at this interesting video: http://tekpub.com/view/concepts/1.

Comment: And this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is dependency injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is eliminating the objects dependencies of concrete classes. 
Benefits:

- It allowed to use an abstract interface instead of a concrete class.
- This makes lots of (large) applications to be more manageable, if you need to swap out a class, its easier to inherit from an interface and make the IoC container switch to another class.

And if you're looking to use DI in ASP.NET Web Forms in the business logic, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection means giving an object its instance variables.

Here is a great article about it:
http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html.
Can't be simplier, I think.

Benefits: Loose coupling. Easy implementation changes by just editing config file. Easy testing with mocks.

In WebForms? Sure, I've been working on a project where we successfully used Castle Windsor to inject our Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Brad Wilson has a really good ASP.NET [MVC 3 Service Location](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html) blog series. It may help you see the value.